# 'git clone ...' works but not 'pip install ...' for the same remote url

Tags: python, git, ssh, pip, pipenv

I want to install a package via pipenv or pip + virtualenv from a private, ssh accessed, remote repository.
While cloning works:

```
git clone git@remoteurl:username/package.git
```

directly installing doesn't:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@remoteurl:username/package.git
```

and outputs the following error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname remoteurl:username: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I tried pip+virtualenv and pipenv, neither works.
I also tried several variations of the url like the following:

```
pip install git@remoteurl:username/package.git

pip install git+git@remoteurl:username/package.git

pip install git+remoteurl:username/package.git

pip install git+ssh://remoteurl:username/package.git
```

all of them produce the same error given above.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ssh://git@remoteurl:username/package.git

That's the wrong syntax for that kind of URLs.

Git understands two syntaxes of SSH URLs:

- `user@host:path/to/repo.git`
- `ssh://user@host/path/to/repo.git`

So, try:

```
$ pip install git+ssh://git@remoteurl/username/package.git
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works now!
For everyone else wondering what the difference was, since I had to read your link 3 times till I discovered, that the second ":" was replaced with a "/".