# Pip install using git+ssh not working for python package

Tags: python-3.x, github, pip, installation

I am trying to install this Python Package:
https://pypi.org/project/SalesforcePy/#install

I am running on python 3.7 on macOS Mojave, I've never experienced an issue downloading a package from github before.

When I tried pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforcePy.git

I get this:

```
Collecting git+ssh://git@github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforcePy.git
  Cloning ssh://git@github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforcePy.git to /private/var/folders/xb/_9gc6p552hz8m7vjc5wbgjbm0000gp/T/pip-req-build-ly43g63b
  Running command git clone -q ssh://git@github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforcePy.git /private/var/folders/xb/_9gc6p552hz8m7vjc5wbgjbm0000gp/T/pip-req-build-ly43g63b
  git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
ERROR: Command "git clone -q ssh://git@github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforcePy.git /private/var/folders/xb/_9gc6p552hz8m7vjc5wbgjbm0000gp/T/pip-req-build-ly43g63b" failed with error code 128 in None
```

I also tried downloading it on my desktop and got this:

```
pip install Desktop/SalesforcePy-1.1.1
Processing ./Desktop/SalesforcePy-1.1.1
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/xb/_9gc6p552hz8m7vjc5wbgjbm0000gp/T/pip-req-build-n3xo0za2/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'requirements.txt')) as fh:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/xb/_9gc6p552hz8m7vjc5wbgjbm0000gp/T/pip-req-build-n3xo0za2/requirements.txt'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/xb/_9gc6p552hz8m7vjc5wbgjbm0000gp/T/pip-req-build-n3xo0za2/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second error message is tracked by [`forcedotcom/SalesforcePy` issue 41](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforcePy/issues/41) and is still pending.

The first one should work though (it is a *public* repository), and [is the recommended method](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforcePy/blob/f35ac2d753148188f77c6fe84f1c0d59aa7d64d1/docs/get_started.rst#from-git). [The syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48689468/6309) is correct (using '`/`' everywhere).
It might be a consequence of the second error message: an error from [`requirement.txt`, which might needs a preprocessing, as in this project](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3610#issuecomment-356687173).